# wpf - have dll callback notify mainwindow

Tags: wpf

I have a 3rd party dll that I am including in a C# WPF project with Dllimport directives.
I have a static c# function that they call as a callback when a certain hardware event occurs.

I would like to accomplish what an old school PostMessage would accomplish. Just notify my mainwindow that the callback occurred. I know I could just get my window and cast and call the mainwindow's function directly but that seems a little flaky. I like the old async PostMessage pattern. Perhaps my question is more about loosely coupling a couple of components in the app.

Should I just invoke a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at using loosely coupled events as you suggest.  Some useful starting points are

- Prism's [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)
- Caliburns's [Event Aggregator](http://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/introduction-to-messaging-with-caliburn-micros-eventaggregator/)
- [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)'s Messenger

which all do similar pub-sub messaging.

I suspect your callback will be on another thread so you'll probably need to use Dispatcher.Invoke to marshal the call to your UI thread.